# convert queryset into pure string only

Tags: django

I have some code that checks if two string matches and they do in the database, but when I query them using this code

```
r = Usertasks.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).filter(randomURL=payment_id).values_list("TaskPostedToNetwork", flat=True)
e = Usertasks.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).filter(randomURL=payment_id).values_list("PaymentConfirmed", flat=True)
```

It returns

```
<QuerySet [False]>
<QuerySet ['yes']>
```

My if loop that checks for the string is never ran because it doesnt return as a string but with the queryset around it, I guess

```
if r == "False" and e == "yes":
   print("Works")
```

How do I make it return just

```
False
yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your query is intended to return just a single value. ie: user and randomURL are unique together. In that case:

```
task = Usertasks.objects.get(user=request.user, randomURL=payment_id)

if not task.TaskPostedToNetwork and task.PaymentConfirmed == 'yes':
    print("Works")
```